# Add multiple events to calendar without opening calendar ..?

Tags: android

I have searched through the forum for my answer,

But all the calendar questions seem to get the same answer.

It appears that the answers given, allows the user to

select the calnder, then the calendar opens for the user

to enter event using the calendar app, then returns to the user's

app once event has been created.

What i'm attempting to do is create a shift planner for my

workmates.

I need the user to be able to enter start date, start time

and shift pattern into edit text, and then my app will

add a event to calendar for each day the shift falls on.

I would like my App to do this without opening the calendar

for each single event, because this would make the app pointless.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction, with regards

to parsing a single event to calendar, without calendar opening.

I will work out the multiple events myself..(easy part :)  )

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android versions prior to 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) did not support a calendar ContentProvider. Currently you can only raise a Calender intent for event entry.